# Custom Sorting in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, sorting

I have JSON field like

```
    {"facebook":"aravind@facebook.com",
            "homeAddress":"26, New Street, Blr",
            "officeAddress":"31, Old Office Street, Blr",
            "city":"Blr",
name:"aravind"
    },
    {"facebook":"ashok@facebook.com",
            "homeAddress":"26, New Street, che",
            "officeAddress":"31, Old Office Street, che",
            "city":"che",
name:"ashok"
    }
```

In Angular js, I have ordered the field by name defaultly,  I have one text box and button

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search.location" />
          <div class="search" ng-click="locationSorting()"></div>
```

When i click the button after  enter the location in text box( For Ex: blr). The list is sorted by location.

Currently i have finishing the filter by location. But i dont want filtering. I want sorting the list

```
 var locationFilterHome = {homeAddress: location};
        filterData = $filter('filter')(data, locationFilterOffice)
```

I am using above code for filtering. How to do sorting based on location

Comment: If you enter `blr` as location , then output should be like first display all records which contain blr as city!! And then all records in ascending/descending order of city's name?? Or am i understanding wrong??

Comment: Normally it is arranged by name like android phone contacts. When i enter the city. It will rearrange by city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you wish to ask how to sort the data by location in the controller.
One way would be to use the 'orderBy' filter. You can use it just like you use the 'filter' filter:  `filterData=$filter('orderBy')(data,'location');`

Please check out this plunk for an example of what I am trying to say: http://plnkr.co/edit/BU4DaxlBSNcmRkXG6krc?p=preview

```
angular.module('app',[])
  .controller('mainCtrl',function($filter){
var data=[{"facebook":"aravind@facebook.com",
                "homeAddress":"26, New Street, Blr",
                "officeAddress":"31, Old Office Street, Blr",
                "city":"Zlr",
    name:"aravind"
        },
        {"facebook":"ashok@facebook.com",
                "homeAddress":"26, New Street, che",
                "officeAddress":"31, Old Office Street, che",
                "city":"che",
    name:"ashok"
        }];

    var modifiedData=$filter('orderBy')(data,'city');
    console.log(modifiedData);
  })
```

Comment: I don't think you can use orderBy for objects, no?

Comment: I can't see your output in plunker

Comment: You have to look at the console since I have done a console.log for the sorted data. Are you unable to get the data in the console?

Comment: Ya Its coming. My aim is. Normally it is ordered by name(A-Z).. When i enter the city in text box(Ex:blr). So Blr field comes first others go down

Answer (score 0):

Your can create filter like this way!!

`bizBrainCommon.filter('test', function () {
    return function (items, field, sortingValue) {
        var filtered = [];

```
    if(!field || !sortingValue)
        return items;

    angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
        filtered.push(item);
    });


    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {

        var upA = a[field].toUpperCase();

        if (upA > sortingValue.toUpperCase() || upA < sortingValue.toUpperCase()) return 1;

        if (upA == sortingValue.toUpperCase())
            return -1;
    });

    return filtered;
};
```

});`

HTML will be like:

`ng-repeat="(id, user) in users |test:'fName': search"`

Hope this will help you!!